# "The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source" in Sharepoint Designer 2007 with SOAP web services

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am working with SharePoint Designer 2007 and trying to connect to a SOAP based web service that uses its own authentication. I am able to connect it via SOAPUI and get teh results successfully.

When I try to connect it via SPD, it shows connection successful. But when I click "Show Data", it returns the generic message stating: "The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source...".